# Scheduling problem (one machine with parallel processing capability)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

Suppose there is a machine, which can hold at most **m** parts in parallel. There is also a production schedule with ***n*** > ***m*** jobs.

An operator now allocates at most ***m*** of the ***n*** jobs to the machine. He then proceeds to work on the parts consecutively, which takes him a part-specific process time ***t_n*** $\in \mathbb{Q}$. Additionally, when he starts working on a part, a part-specific "drying time" starts, which will take ***td_n***  $\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Only if all drying times and all processing times are completed, the parts can be removed and new parts can be allocated. In a more complex scenario, ***t_n*** and ***t_dn*** could both be stochastic. In the simpler case, both times are deterministic; then an overall processing time ***to_n = max(t_n, td_n)*** can be considered.

The question is now, how the total production duration for the entire schedule can be minimized: I am looking for possible approaches, not solutions.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So far, I am just looking for ideas on how that could be solved. I have edited the question slightly (to make it more complex) and have added some ideas.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that dynamic traveling salesman will only work for **t_n**

Comment: I don't know about dynamic traveling salesman, but the standard, non-dynamic, traveling salesman only takes exponential time. So unless the the additional complexity due to the drying times is worse than exponential, I see no reason why the total production for the entire schedule cannot be minimized using traveling salesman.

Comment: Is "starts working" a typo for "stops working"?  Also, must the machine always hold exactly $m$ parts, or can it be $\le m$?

Comment: @robPratt I have edited the question. It's not a typo, but only relevant in the more complex case that both are stochastic, I guess. And it could be <= m, but I think that makes no sense?

Comment: It is conceivable that you would sometimes put fewer than $m$ parts in the machine because a part with a long drying time could otherwise delay allocating new parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ib}$ indicate whether job $i$ is assigned to batch $b$, let binary decision variable $y_{ij}$ indicate whether job $i$ precedes (not necessarily immediately) job $j$, let $s_i \ge 0$ be the start time of job $i$, and let $z_b$ be the finish time of batch $b$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_b z_b$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_b x_{ib} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_i x_{ib} &\le m &&\text{for all $b$} \tag2\label2\\
x_{ib} + x_{jb} - 1 &\le y_{ij} + y_{ji} &&\text{for all $i<j$ and $b$} \tag3\label3\\
s_i + t_i - s_j &\le M_{ij}(1-y_{ij}) &&\text{for all $i\not=j$} \tag4\label4\\
s_i + \max(t_i, td_i) - z_b &\le M'_{ib}(1-x_{ib}) &&\text{for all $i$ and $b$} \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns each job to exactly one batch.
Constraint \eqref{2} assigns at most $m$ jobs to each batch.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the logical implication $(x_{ib} \land x_{jb}) \implies (y_{ij} \lor y_{ji})$.
Big-M constraint \eqref{4} enforces the logical implication $y_{ij} \implies s_i + t_i \le s_j$.
Big-M constraint \eqref{5} enforces the logical implication $x_{ib} \implies s_i + \max(t_i,td_i) \le z_b$.

This compact formulation motivates a column generation formulation with a set partitioning master problem and one column per batch.